# How to always share "Seagate Expansion" as F

Tags: networking, network-shares, windows-server-2008, shared-folders

We have 10 "Seagate Expansion" drives that we use in rotation as backup storage devices. Whenever we swap the drives over the share gets broken.

Is it possible since all the drives have the same name that we can keep the share as "F" whenever we swap the drives?

I have looked in the properties of the drives but cant see anything that looks like it will help remember the shared letter on the drive.

We are using them on a Windows Server 2008

Comment: Drives can (and often will) have an unique number. Consider it a serial number. Windows will notice that the disk has changed unless you make sure that all drives have the same 'serial'.  (Note that may cause confusion if you ever try to use two disks with the same unique 'serial' and an other solution might be better).

Comment: Also. Segate drives? Or Seagate drives? And expansion? (with one less A) ?

Comment: @Hennes how would you give the drives the same 'serial'?

Comment: I just googled. I did not even consider that someone would use USB drives with server 2008. I assumed eSATA.  But in this case the link you posted should work.

Comment: As answer(s) on the duplicate I pointed to explains: If you assign a USB drive a letter via the Disk Management in Windows that copy of Windows will always use that letter for that drive (if it's available).  Plug in each drive (one at a time), assign it a letter (say "X:"), eject it, repeat for next drive.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007: This method does not work for me using two microSD cards in the same microSD slot in Windows 10. Each time I set one drive to the desired letter, then eject it, then plug in the other one, it will have "forgotten" the set drive letter and come up as some other one. Should I open a new question?